# tag cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: php, android, android-intent, android-activity, textview

I have a tag resolving error which I have beeen trying to slove but all in vain,
I want to move data from one activity to another but I am getting this error:

------>    "tag cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View view) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), home.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("NAME", name);
        startActivity(newActivity);
        Log.d(TAG, name);
    }  
});
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

LoginActivity1.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin;
import org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpec;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.trekeyes.android.CustomHttpClient;

public class LoginActivity1 extends Activity { 

    Button btnLinkToRegistrScrn; 
    Button loginbtn1;
    Button cancelBtn;
    TextView error;
    EditText LgnTxt, LgnPsw; 
    public static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    public static String TAG="LoginActivity1";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.login); 
     LgnTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLgnEmail);
     LgnPsw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLgnPassword);
     error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_error1);
     addListenerOnButton(); 


     // Link to Register Screen  
        btnLinkToRegistrScrn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LinkToRegisterScreen);  
        btnLinkToRegistrScrn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
           @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {  
               finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity.class);  
                startActivity(i); 
                }});


     // Link to Cancel Button 
        cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelLgn);  
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
           @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {  
               finish();
              //  Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), PageApp.class);  
              //  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
              //  startActivity(i); 
                }  
       });
   } 
    public void addListenerOnButton() { 

             loginbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin); 

            loginbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 

                ///////// Database Handling

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


               ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", LgnTxt.getText().toString()));
                   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", LgnPsw.getText().toString()));

                   String response = null;
                   try {
                             response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/db/lgn.php", postParameters);  
                       String res=response.toString();
                   res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                   if(res.equals("1"))
                   {
                       error.setText("Correct Email And Password");
                              Intent intent = new Intent(arg0.getContext(), boardAct.class); 
                              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                                intent.putExtra("EMAIL", LgnTxt.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                                Log.d(TAG,LgnTxt.getText().toString());
                                finish(); 
                   }

                   else
                   error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Email or Password");

                   } catch (Exception e) {

                   LgnTxt.setText(e.toString());
                   }           

      }

        }); 
    } 

 }
```

boardAct.java

```
public class boardAct extends MapActivity {

    public static String TAG="boardAct";


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
}
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/accountSettings"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtlabellogSetting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:state_enabled="false"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/labelsettings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtboxlogSetting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:state_enabled="false"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting.java

```
public class AccSettingsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        addListenerOnButton();    
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          ///////////// For TxtlogSetting  ////////////

            TextView logText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtboxlogSetting); 
            String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL"); 
            logText.setText("email");   
   }
```

Comment: Is TAG declared in the new activity?

Comment: no I haven't yet declared TAG in another activty

Comment: So...that's your problem. You can't reference a variable that you haven't declared.

Comment: Now I have declared in both activties but still showing this error:
tag cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare TAG as Activity level field before onCreate of Activity as:

```
public class Your_Main_Activity extends Activity {
    public static String TAG="YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME";
    Button ok;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(Your_Main_Activity.this, home.class);
                newActivity.putExtra("NAME", name.toString());
                startActivity(newActivity);
                Log.d(TAG, name.toString());
            }  
        });
        // your code here
    }
}
```

if you have already declared it in other activity as static then access it as:

```
Log.d(Your_Other_Activity.TAG, name.toString());
```

Comment: ThankYou very much for your valuable answer. I did as you posted but I am getting this error in "Log.d" which is "The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, Editable)"

Comment: @CoolJCoolie : what is `name` ? if it is EditText then use `name.setText().toString()` instead of name

Comment: @CoolJCoolie :any success friend

Comment: Great the error is gone! Now what do I have to do on the next actvity, pl. need your help

Comment: @CoolJCoolie : what you are doing in next Activity ?

Comment: When the user logins successfully, then in next activty I want to show name and email address of that user in my dashboard activity. Thanks once again, you are a great help

Comment: I am getting error in "getStringExtra"  
Do I have to include this one line only in next activty?

Comment: @CoolJCoolie : sorry use `String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");`

Comment: Edited it, now checking on emulator :)

Comment: I am doing like this, but getting nothing in the Edittext:

EditText logText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtboxlogSetting);
String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL");
String logTextS = logText.toString();
logTextS = email;

Comment: You need to do this: EditText logText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtboxlogSetting); String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL"); logText.setText(email);

Comment: @DavidWasser I am getting no value, its empty

Comment: @CoolJCoolie : hi, still facing issue?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Hi, yeah I am getting no value in edittext, it shows empty :(

Comment: @CoolJCoolie : edit your post with latest code of both activity

Comment: Sorry I dont know why i am getting force close error and logcat is pointing at "Email = extras.getString("EMAIL");" line

Comment: Sorry I am still getting force close error when I go to AccSettingsActivity but logcat is showing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`TAG` should be declared somewhere. As it is all caps, I suspect it's a

```
public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
```

Be sure to declare and instantiate that variable if you plan on using that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String TAG = "NAME"

Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View view) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(),home.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("NAME", name);
        startActivity(newActivity);
        Log.d(TAG,name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

declare String TAG = "activityName"; before using TAG variable
you can remove this line as well as it has nothing to do with your functionality. Now to get data which you have passed via intent to next activity you can do this in onCreate() method of your next activity

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME", "");
```